# Kafka ByteArrayDeserializer to read avro messages in Spark DStreams

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to use Kafka ByteArrayDeserializer to read avro records from a Kafka topic. But getting below exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

My Code:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(1))

  val kafkaParams: Map[String, Object] = Map(
    "bootstrap.servers" -> "kafka-server:9092",
    "key.serializer" -> classOf[StringSerializer],
    "value.serializer" -> classOf[StringSerializer],
    "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
    "value.deserializer" -> classOf[ByteArrayDeserializer],
    "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
    "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean),
    "security.protocol" -> "SSL",
    "ssl.truststore.location" -> "truststore",
    "ssl.truststore.password" -> "pass",
    "ssl.keystore.location" -> "keystore.jks",
    "ssl.keystore.password" -> "pass",
    "group.id" -> "group1"
  )

val topics: Array[String] = Array("topics")

val kafkaDstream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
    ssc,
    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
    ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
  )

val schema = parser.parse(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("avro2.avsc"))))
val datumReader = new SpecificDatumReader[GenericRecord](schema)

val processedStream = kafkaDstream.map(record => {
    val x = new ByteArrayInputStream(record.value().getBytes())  // throwing exception here
    val binaryDecoder = DecoderFactory.get.binaryDecoder(x, null)
    datumReader.read(null, binaryDecoder)
  })


processedStream.map(rec => rec.get("taskId")).print
```

Any help is appretiated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `Subscribe[String, String]`.

You want `Subscribe[String, Array[Byte]]`

Then `record.value()` is already a byte array, not having a getBytes method

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.String

This exception is to say that there's an object of type `[B` was cast to `java.lang.String` and failed.

`[B` is a [string representation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) of `Array[Byte]`:

```
jshell> byte[] bytes = new byte[10]
bytes ==> byte[10] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }

jshell> bytes.toString()
$2 ==> "[B@6e8cf4c6"
```

*"Why does this even happen?"* you ask. It's because the following line (silently) assumes that whatever you're doing can ever be a `String`.

```
val x = new ByteArrayInputStream(record.value().getBytes())  // throwing exception here
```

### Final Note

Please use [Spark Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) instead. You won't regret this decision.